# Java Spring, how to do @scheduled work in thread pool?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/15 * * * * *")
    private void verify() {
        SortEvent event;
        while ((event = verificationQueue.poll()) != null) {
            Target target = taskRepository.findById(event.targetId).orElse(null);
            if (target == null) {
                continue;
            }
            collector.collect(target, event.date);
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
    private void event() {
        SortEvent event;
        while ((event = eventQueue.poll()) != null) {
            Target target = taskRepository.findById(event.targetId).orElse(null);
            if (target == null) {
                continue;
            }
            collector.collect(target, event.date);
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    private void consume() {
        SortEvent event;
        while ((event = ConsumeQueue.poll()) != null) {
            Target target = taskRepository.findById(event.targetId).orElse(null);
            if (target == null) {
                continue;
            }
            collector.collect(target, event.date);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to configure scheduled tasks to run in a threaded manner to avoid them affecting each other, as it seems they're being processed slightly slower than the desired interval?

I'd prefer if all scheduled tasks run independently without overlapping and execute in their own threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 2 way:

1.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("name");
        scheduler.initialize();

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(scheduler);
    }
}
```

2. 

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private final int POOL_SIZE = 10;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {

        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(this.poolScheduler());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();

        scheduler.setPoolSize(POOL_SIZE);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("name");

        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Second way is better later you can use **TaskScheduler** in other classes using **@Autowired**

Answer (score 0):

correctly, `@Scheduled` runs on the same thread, causing issues. Therefore, you need to configure it separately using `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`.

here is an example code.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(10); // Set the pool size as needed
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("my-scheduled-task-");
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}
```